# SQLite Dynamic SQL to insert into ListView/TextView? (Guidance needed)

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, listview, dynamic-sql

I had an original question where I wanted to know how to search the sqlite db and retrieve rows for calculation. --> [Search SQLite Database and use values from retrieved rows for calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21187645/search-sqlite-database-and-use-values-from-retrieved-rows-for-calculation)

It turns out that a basic sql query won't work as I planned. This is b/c I realized that the values in the table aren't known until the user enters them in.

[The basic premise of the app allows the user to add information regarding the item and it's price. The Listview right now just pulls that information as is off the DB. But I want the ListView to search the DB for items that have the same value, and consolidate it into single view of the ListView. That view would also calculate the average price calculated from the DB if that item had more than one instance entered. Clicking the item in the list would reveal it's "history", e.g. other times the instances were entered.]

I am thinking that dynamic SQL will solve this issue with the search and calculation but I'm not sure if it's the right track. I am thinking that it would also be used for the 2nd half where you click on the item to look at the history. Can anybody tell me if this is the right train of thought and maybe a good resource to study if that is the case.

Would prefer to try and study & improve my problem solving first rather than just ask about the code

Thanks so much if anyone can provide guidance.

Answer (score 0):

**[ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html)** actually consists of multiple rows of data either coming from static Arrays, ArrayList, [SqliteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) any API. It depends on you what, Adapter you want to use to feed in data to you ListView.

Now the next thing which you, want to do is some calculation, so i suggest create a custom layout view for the rows. So that you can do some calculations in Adapter and set the values inside it in TextViews.

[ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) has got [onItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) method you can start a new Activity so show the details.

For working on Custom ListView follow this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/).

Comment: I do have a separate layout view that is being called in my listview actually. What I don`t know how to deal with calling the data from the sqlite database to do the calculations since I don`t know the values until runtime.